# US Non-Polarized Plug Dimensions

Tags: plug, dimensions

for academic purposes I'm  doing a very specific task where i need to calculate the Cell Constant of an American Non-Polarized Plug, ie, without  same length the prongs. 
So I need to know what are the dimensions of it, namely, **length, thickness,wide and distance** between the probes.

I cannot get the dimensions for this plugs anywhere on the internet , only from polarized ones,  so if any kind soul with one at home could give I would be very appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: There aren't supposed to be any non-polarized available anywhere, except grandfathered in on very old devices.

Comment: You'll be close enough if you assume the blades of the non polarized plug are the same as the narrower blade on a polarized plug.

Comment: There are polarized non-grounded plugs - they have the wider Neutral pin, but no ground pin.  I have some power tools and a two-wire extension cord that have these plugs (No, I didn't break the ground pin off!)

Comment: What is a Cell Constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an non-polarized adapter from by visit in the US, and can measure the dimensions for you. So these are no official values:

```
Thickness:           1.4mm  
Width:               6.2mm  
Length:             16.2mm  
Distance:           11.4mm
Hole diameter:       3.2mm
Distance hole - tip: 3.2mm
```

In addition, there's a hole of 3.2mm diameter in each probe, 3.2mm apart from the tip